# How do I debug a silent VB6 crash?

Tags: vb6

I am experiencing random crashes when I use my VB6 app in runtime mode.

I have read about Dr. Watson, but I don't even find it on the internt anymore.

What could I do to track down the bug?

Edit: I am pretty sure that the crash happens because I call

```
SomeArray(SomeIndex)
```

and SomeIndex is > UBound(SomeArray)

The reason it crashes silently seem to be that this error occurs within a subclassing procedure.

But I would like to know how I could have found out about it if I had not been able to pinpoint the error.

Thank you!

Comment: What does your application do?  What do the crashes look like?  Is there an error message?  When did they start?  Has anything changed before the crashes started?  Do you have the source code?  Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: @eglease Thanks, I have edited my post and added some clues. So I know why it happens, but I would like to know if there would have any way to simply detect the error even when VB6 crashes silently. I have error catches like On Error Goto ... , and error logs are written, but this error is not thrown, the app just dies before it can write the log, I think.

Comment: `I have error catches like On Error Goto` - are they in the subclassing procedure too?

Comment: @GSerg Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code in question...

Comment: Is the problem reproducible when you run it from VisualStudio?  If not, you can add some logging to see exactly where it fails and what values it fails with.  We can give better suggestions if you can show us some code.

Comment: Use the system debugger - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/brief-introduction-to-windows-debugger.html. Make sure you read the paragraph on setting up VB6 program.

Comment: A good place to start, to get an idea, is the Windows Event viewer, Windows Logs, Application Logs.  It might not tell you why or where, but it might tell you what..  Beyond that, the suggestion about logs to get the exact line, followed by the stark reality that you can't change the component, so simply don't do what's breaking.  Subclassing is notorious for it.  If necessary, whittle back your program to the minimal viable crasher, and then re-engineer your code to do it a different way.

Comment: Add logging so you can see what lines are executed?

Comment: Since you mention you pretty sure the error trigger in `SomeArray(SomeIndex)` when SomeIndex is > UBound(SomeArray), why not you put an `if` before `SomeArray(SomeIndex)`?